# Is there a way to restrict mouse movement within a certain region in X11?

Tags: c, x11, motif

I have a C application developed with X/Motif and I would like restrict the mouse movement to stay within certain boundaries, not necessarily the main window itself. I found about the XGrabPointer method, which can confine the pointer to a window, but I want the mouse to be confined to an even smaller rectangle whenever the app is running, for safety reasons. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What safety reasons could these be? Just write your app in a way that it won't react to mouse actions outside the specified region in the "unsafe" way.

Comment: The app is running as a fallback to another app, and it only goes to the foreground when the main one crashes. In that fallback mode, the user shouldn't be able to access the rest of the screen, as there could be some other windows running there. The user should only be able to use the fallback application which runs on half the screen.

Comment: can you make a window that covers half the screen and then grab the pointer to that window? Can you just *not run all the stuff you don't want the user to be able to click on*?